# Automatically Open and Close Database Connection Within a Method

Tags: c#

I have recently been put on an existing project and am trying to reduce the amount of duplicate code.

Right now there are many methods relating to database interaction. The Database connection is opened and closed within each of these methods. Essentially, the exact same code is used in every single method to open and close the connection.

```
    public static void AddToTable()
    { 
        DbConnection con = Common.CreateConnection();
        DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        //cmd.CommandText = SQL COMMAND GOES HERE
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
```

I understand the importance of opening and closing the connection but seeing these exact same lines of code in every method smells funny to me.

Does C# have some kind of way I could accomplish automatically creating the connection (in this case the con and cmd variables) when the method is started and then closing the connection when the method is finished?

Comment: You're looking for the `using` statement.

Comment: Looks like you might also be able to refactor database command execution into a another method that accepts your command text as a parameter.

Comment: @MichaelPetito I thought about that but many of the database commands will have custom parameters and I feel that would get very messy very quickly. The example in my post excluded this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void AddToTable()
{ 
    using( DbConnection con = Common.CreateConnection() ) 
    {
      DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

      //cmd.CommandText = SQL COMMAND GOES HERE
      //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

Because the DBConnection is inside the `using` and DbConnection implements the interface `IDisposable` the connections `.Dispose()` method will be executed once it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
using(var con = Common.CreateConnection())
{
  using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
  {
      //cmd.CommandText = SQL COMMAND GOES HERE
      //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

This will automatically close the connection when disposing of the `cmd` and `con` objects after closing the `using` block(s).  It doesn't refactor out the *creation* of those objects, but honestly that shouldn't be refactored out anyway.  It's best to keep those objects entirely within the scope of the method using them.  Repeated code isn't *that* distasteful when it's repeated for a very good reason.  (Indeed, one can argue that this isn't even repeated code since it's used for different business purposes.  It's simply repeated *keystrokes*.  Andy typing keystrokes into the IDE isn't the difficult part of software development, maintaining the code and abstractions therein is.)

Comment: command typically isn't required unless you are using an OleDbCommand or OdBcCommand, but it's a good practice non the less.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is doing database operations then you need to Open and Close database connections in the same method itself if no such requirement to open the connection indefinitely.
If you use 'Using' statement the compiler will convert the code to try/finally block.

See below,

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
      sqlConn.Open();

}
```

The compiler will convert this code as below.

```
try
{
     SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
     sqlConn.Open();

}
finally
{
     sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: it will actually call `sqlConn.Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `using` blocks consider also the unit-of-work pattern which is used in Entity Framework for example. The main idea is to pick some logical parts of the app's DB work into a single unit and have a single connection open&close for each unit. Your method is called AddToTable so we can assume working with some concrete table data which itself is a set of some essences (rows in this table). One of the possible approaches in this case is to consider a unit of work as a set of operations with a single essence in a table like CRUD. The lifecycle of DB connection would be: open connection - CRUD single essence - close connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create helper method to move repeatable code into it. Something like

```
public static void WithDB(Action<SqlConnection, DbCommand> action)
{
    using(var con = Common.CreateConnection())
    {
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        action(con, cmd);
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
public static void AddToTable()
{
    WithDB((con, cmd)=>
    { 
        //cmd.CommandText = SQL COMMAND GOES HERE
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    });

}
```

[Proof](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N7ivbW).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is your friend.... (actually just spent time refactoring 400+ using statements down so there is only one place where the sqlcommand is created (and it is a using statement)